# Joining two SQL tables directly OR via junction table

Tags: sql-server, join, crystal-reports, left-join

I've been grappling with a problem for some time, checking thread after thread on S/O to no avail. I should mention I'm building a SQL query for use in Crystal Reports.

I am attempting to join two tables together that MAY be joined via a junction table - this can be done via UNIONs but the table then links to itself and it can become very messy accounting for all potential scenarios.

Let's say we have three tables: t1, t2 and t3.

I'm after a quick and reusable way to say "LEFT JOIN t1 & t2 directly OR LEFT JOIN via table3".

Here's a really basic knock-up of what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID
FROM   t AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
       t AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.parentID OR (
       t AS t2 ON t1.ID = t3.ID1 AND t3.ID2 = t2.ID ))
```

Is this at all possible without ending up with two versions of t2? 
I'm hoping there's a function out there I'm just unaware of.

EDIT: the direct t2 join is to a 'parentId' column on t2 and t1 & t2 are aliases of the same column.

Here's my desired output:

```
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------------+
| t1.ID | t3.ID1 | t3.ID2 | t2.ID | t2.parentID |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------------+
|   001 | NULL   | NULL   | 004   | 001         |
|   002 | 002    | 003    | 003   | NULL        |
|   003 | NULL   | NULL   | NULL  | NULL        |
+-------+--------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: One example would be great also include table schema. Sample Data and Desire Output.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Assuming you will using a sql view of some sort and then use it in CR. If you dont wish to use sql view, and do the joining in the report itself using the DbExpert, I have found using Aliases for tables useful. That way you can use 2 instances of the same table completely independent of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably close to your request. But if `t3.ID1` is on the same domain than `t2.ID` you can have problems

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.ID
FROM   t1
LEFT JOIN t3
       ON t1.ID = t3.ID1
LEFT JOIN t2
       ON t1.ID = t2.ID
       OR t3.ID2 = t2.ID
```

So maybe you can include some validations

```
SELECT S.ID1, COALESCE(S.ID2, T2.ID) 
FROM 
    (   SELECT t1.ID as ID1, t2.ID as ID2
        FROM   t1
        LEFT JOIN t2
               ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
               -- This step look weird if t1.ID = t2.ID you just print same ID twice.
    ) as S
 LEFT JOIN t3
        ON S.ID1 = t3.ID1
       AND S.ID2 IS NULL -- ONLY JOIN IF NOT MATCH ON FIRST QUERY 
 LEFT JOIN t2
        ON t2.ID1 = t2.ID
```

Comment: @LiceRewis I see, but you didnt include sample data. You have to add that so I can adapt my query to that source.